# MongoDB 3.2 Update Field name in embedded array

Tags: mongodb, migration, bulkupdate

Im trying to do a i migration in my MongoDB. I have updated a Field from Content -> StringContent. Now I want to update all records that exists with the new Field name.

This is how a document looks like.

```
{
"_id" : "c4af0b19-4c78-4e58-bbe5-ac9e5cce2c3f",
"Type" : "Onboarding",
"Cards" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : LUUID("3f328a1c-658d-ee4e-8f06-561760eb5be5"),
        "Width" : 1,
        "Title" : "",
        "Type" : "Freetext",
        "Description" : "",
        "Content" : "This is a test" // -> "StringContent" : "This is a Test"
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : LUUID("2f328a1c-658d-ee4e-8f06-561760eb5be5"),
        "Width" : 1,
        "Title" : "",
        "Type" : "Freetext",
        "Description" : "",
        "Content" : "This is another test" //-> "StringContent" : "This is another Test"            
    }
],
"DocumentType" : "Template",
"History" : [ 
    {
        "Date" : ISODate("2017-07-13T12:03:01.620Z"),
        "ByUserId" : LUUID("4ecaa6ca-2ce6-f84c-81f3-28f8f0256e6e")
    }
],
"Name" : "Default Template"
}
```

I have created this script:

```
        var bulk = db.getCollection('OnboardingPortal').initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

     db.getCollection('OnboardingPortal').find({"DocumentType": "Template"}).
forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.Cards.forEach(function(card) {

        if(card.hasOwnProperty("Content")){
            print(card);
            bulk.find({"_id": doc._id, "Cards._id": card._id}).update(
            {
                $set: {"Cards.$.StringContent": card.Content}
            });
            bulk.find({"_id": doc._id, "Cards._id": card._id}).update(
            {
                $unset: {"Cards.$.Content": 1}
            });

            count += 2;
            if(count % 500 == 0) {
                bulk.execute();
                bulk = db.getCollection('OnboardingPortal').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
            }
        }
    });
});
if ( count % 500 !== 0 ){
    bulk.execute();      
}
```

This Does not update anything, but if I change `bulk.operations` -> to explicit set index on array like this, it will do the job. but only for one card :

```
bulk.find({"_id": doc._id, "Cards.1._id": card._id}).update(
            {
                $set: {"Cards.1.StringContent": card.Content}
            });
            bulk.find({"_id": doc._id, "Cards.1._id": card._id}).update(
            {
                $unset: {"Cards.1.Content": 1}
            });
```

What am i missing in my script so this can iterates over several documents and change Content-> StringContent in each Card. ?

**EDIT**

I have added a `bulk.getOperations();` in my script. this is what it returns. Should it not have replaced `$` with index ?

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "originalZeroIndex" : 0.0,
        "batchType" : 2.0,
        "operations" : [ 
            {
                "q" : {
                    "_id" : "c4af0b19-4c78-4e58-bbe5-ac9e5cce2c3f",
                    "Cards._id" : "1c8a323f-8d65-4eee-8f06-561760eb5be5"
                },
                "u" : {
                    "$set" : {
                        "Cards.$.StringContent" : "This is a cool test"
                    }
                },
                "multi" : false,
                "upsert" : false
            }, 
            {
                "q" : {
                    "_id" : "c4af0b19-4c78-4e58-bbe5-ac9e5cce2c3f",
                    "Cards._id" : "1c8a323f-8d65-4eee-8f06-561760eb5be5"
                },
                "u" : {
                    "$unset" : {
                        "Cards.$.Content" : 1.0
                    }
                },
                "multi" : false,
                "upsert" : false
            }, 
            {
                "q" : {
                    "_id" : "c4af0b19-4c78-4e58-bbe5-ac9e5cce2c3f",
                    "Cards._id" : "1c8a322f-8d65-4eee-8f06-561760eb5be5"
                },
                "u" : {
                    "$set" : {
                        "Cards.$.StringContent" : "This is a test"
                    }
                },
                "multi" : false,
                "upsert" : false
            }, 
            {
                "q" : {
                    "_id" : "c4af0b19-4c78-4e58-bbe5-ac9e5cce2c3f",
                    "Cards._id" : "1c8a322f-8d65-4eee-8f06-561760eb5be5"
                },
                "u" : {
                    "$unset" : {
                        "Cards.$.Content" : 1.0
                    }
                },
                "multi" : false,
                "upsert" : false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Possibly could have something to do with the `BinData` type not matching. Where are you actually running this? In the shell? The usage of `.getCollection()` suggests Robo3T. And if the latter is the case then I suggest you make sure to upgrade to the latest version. Bugs in the product are quite frequent.

Comment: I run this in RoboMongo's shell. Will check

Comment: @NeilLunn I have downloaded Robo3T, still not working. I have aslo tried to run this in the CosmosDB shell in azure but there I get a error stating: `ERROR: initializeOrderedBulkOp is not a function on collections.
TypeError: $__temp__[3] is not a function `

Comment: Ahh! CosmosDB is not MongoDB. That's a very important part you did not mention. I'm actually kind of over ranting about the deception that CosmosDB can be a "drop in replacement" for MongoDB. It's all lies. Basically put, don't expect MongoDB things to work on something that is not MongoDB.